# NuGet Local Package Not Found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am currently in the process of upgrading from Entity Framework 4.0 to 5.0. In order to do this I am required to open the Visual Studio package manager and  execute:

`install-package entityframework -pre`

The problem is, when I run this command I get the following error message:
[image]

The problem is, 'gmts-logger' is not a NuGet package, it is a local project, so I don't understand why NuGet has anything to do with it.
I'm stumped. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when gmts-logger does not exist on the way provided in Reference path. 
Try to do following steps:

- Right click your project and choose Unload Project
- After it's unloaded right click your solution and pick edit your project
- find Reference for gmts-logger and correct path where it physically exists
- Reload project and via NuGet Package manager install entityframework

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by navigating to each of my projects and removing all references to 'gmts-logger' from all of the 'packages.config' files.

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolved your issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue. Thanks.